# what is the difference between refresh rate and frame rate?

Tags: screen, frame-rate

please can any one explain for me , what is the difference between **refresh rate** and **frame rate**?

in the Wikipedia I found this definition for refresh rate "is the number of times in a second that a display hardware updates its buffer"  , but what that mean , does that mean that if we wrote a JavaScript function that changes a style of an element periodically  we have to wait until my screen refresh to see that change ????

please help me I am confused a little.

Comment: Have you read the rest of the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refresh_rate); it explains the difference quite clearly. Yes, you will have to "wait" for the frame to advance to see the change, but that happens tens of times per second!

Comment: thanx to you , but  when somebody sees that  things are getting more complicated he will not be  able to complete reading ,  so that I asked you  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Frame rate

> Frame rate, also known as frame frequency and frames per second (FPS),
>   is the frequency (rate) at which an imaging device produces unique
>   consecutive images called frames. The term applies equally well to
>   film and video cameras, computer graphics, and motion capture systems.
>   Frame rate is most often expressed in frames per second (FPS) and is
>   also expressed in progressive scan monitors as hertz (Hz).

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate)

#### Refresh rate

> The refresh rate (most commonly the "vertical refresh rate", "vertical
>   scan rate" for cathode ray tubes) is the number of times in a second
>   that a display hardware updates its buffer. This is distinct from the
>   measure of frame rate in that the refresh rate includes the repeated
>   drawing of identical frames, while frame rate measures how often a
>   video source can feed an entire frame of new data to a display.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refresh_rate)